# Rails console vs server differences on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dreamhost, fastcgi

Having deployed a very basic Rails 3.2.3 trial site to a "production" server (not really in production, thankfully!) with RVM Ruby 1.9.3-p194, I find the following to be true, of the commands listed here:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╤═══╗
║ command issued                       │OK?║
╟──────────────────────────────────────┼───╢
║ bundle exec rails console            │ N ║
║ bundle exec rails console production │ Y ║
║ bundle exec rails server             │ Y ║
║ bundle exec rails server production  │ N ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╧═══╝
```

**My first question: is this expected?** (I would have thought the pattern in the right column should be N-Y-N-Y.)

More info: `bundle exec rails console` fails for the understandable reason that the *sqlite3* gem is not installed on the server. However, `bundle exec rails server production` fails with a much less understandable trace:

```
$ bundle exec rails server production
Exiting
/home/spkspike/www/spike.sampablokuper.com/releases/20120530134819/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:63:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/production (LoadError)
from /home/spkspike/www/spike.sampablokuper.com/releases/20120530134819/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:63:in `try_require'
from /home/spkspike/www/spike.sampablokuper.com/releases/20120530134819/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:16:in `get'
from /home/spkspike/www/spike.sampablokuper.com/releases/20120530134819/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:269:in `server'
from /home/spkspike/www/spike.sampablokuper.com/releases/20120530134819/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `start'
from /home/spkspike/www/spike.sampablokuper.com/releases/20120530134819/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/spkspike/www/spike.sampablokuper.com/releases/20120530134819/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /home/spkspike/www/spike.sampablokuper.com/releases/20120530134819/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

**My second question: how best to troubleshoot this error?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't you want to be starting the server in production mode using the production environment?

```
rails server -e production
```

The syntax difference between rails console environment and rails server -e environment is a bit of a PITA

Comment: For thin server this is correct....Also for Webrick you will need to run RAILS_ENV=production rails s

Answer (score 3):

In case of console production specifies the environment and in case of server it specifies something else (probably which server to use webrick/...).

So if you want to specify the enviroment do:

```
ENV=production rails server
```